# Couldn't import cv2 in SageMaker Studio Lab

Tags: opencv, amazon-sagemaker

I tried importing cv2 from opencv but i got error saying

> import error: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Since Sagemaker Studio Labs doesn't support installation of Ubuntu packages i couldn't use `apt-get` or `yum` to install libglib2.0-0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fix this by:

`!pip uninstall opencv-python -y`

Then use the **headless** version instead with studio:

`!pip install opencv-python-headless`

Ref: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/1773

Answer (score 1):

With this line, you can install the glib dependency for Amazon Sagemaker Studio Lab. Just run it on your notebook cell.

```
! conda install glib=2.51.0 -y
```

You also can create another virtual environment for your session that contains glib:

```
! conda create -n glib-test -c defaults -c conda-forge python=3 glib=2.51.0` -y
```

After that maybe you need albumentations to import cv2:

```
! pip install albumentations
```